# Does AutoComplete Outlook 2016 cost any money/bandwidth/memory to the company?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, autocomplete, microsoft-outlook-2016

Does it cost money or does it consume any resources to have the AutoComplete feature enabled in Microsoft Outlook?

The IT disabled (greyed out) the AutoComplete for contact names in Outlook 2016 for everyone, because "it costs tens of thousands of euros to keep it on". I just have to know if their explanation has any truth in it, or are they making stuff up.

I can't even describe how essential is that feature, and the caching for it is clearly at a computer level, because if I log on to another workstation, I won't have my AutoComplete list anyway. This whole thing is inconceivable to me, and if someone could give me a rational explanation, I would at least understand why is (figuratively) my hand being tied behind by back.

Comment: I have no idea what they are doing. The explanation is preposterous. It is a useful and necessary feature in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

It might be that the cost is due to people mindlessly using the auto complete and sending sensitive data to customers or competitors.

For example they meant to send the quarterly report to Joseph in Accounts so they type "jo" but because they don't pay attention it goes to the Johannesburg Times who they like to send rant emails to during their lunch breaks.

Turning off auto complete forces people to use the address book to manage contacts and eliminates errors of convenience.

Comment: Mindless people can also use the address book mindlessly. And again, the decrease in efficiency of everyone else costs a lot more money. But still, why wouldn't they just say that, rather than concocting a reason that defies logic? It makes me wonder if the IT is condescending ("all employees have tiny minds to understand the bigger picture") or just flat out lying out of laziness ("let's tell them this, it's shorter")